# Why would legitimate "corporate trustees such as banks" act, when "they have not even been asked by the testator whether they will act"?

Tags: wills, trusts-and-estates

I am befuddled by Fox LJ in  [*Re Duke of Norfolk’s ST* [1982] Ch 61](https://lawcarenigeria.com/duke-of-norfolks-settlement-trusts-re-1981-ewca-civ-5-13-april-1981/).

> But very frequently executors and trustees of wills
> know nothing of the terms of the will until the testator is dead; sometimes in the case of
> **corporate trustees such as banks, they have not even been asked by the testator whether
> they will act. [emphasis added]** It is difficult to see with whom, in such cases, the trustees are to be taken to
> be contracting. The appointment of a trustee by the court also gives rise to problems as to
> the identity of the contracting party.’

What the hey? What legal banks in the UK would act for a testator, let alone ANYBODY, if **"they have not even been asked by the testator whether they will act"** ?

I asked everyone I know, but nobody ever heard of such a bank! We have dealt with all the big banks in the UK. Customers must always prove their identity, fulfill the bank's requirements such as credit check, before banks open an account, let alone act for customers. Then banks require instructions in writing, before they act for customers! We know all this from experience. I opened my first personal and commercial bank account in the 1970's. Until 2010's, I had to meet face to face with a banker, before a bank acted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What legal banks in the UK would act for a testator, let alone
> ANYBODY, if "they have not even been asked by the testator whether
> they will act"?

Almost all of them. It's their business. It's what they do. As long as they can be paid their ordinary and customary rate for the work, they'll do it (some banks have a minimum estate/trust size that they'll handle, because smaller estates can't generate enough fees to be profitable).

While the bank isn't obligated to take on the job, it almost always does. I've seen a bank reject an appointment once (in a case where there it was large enough to be profitable for the bank), in a case where I represented some of the decedent's next of kin, in a quarter century of practice, out of maybe a hundred appointments. The case involved a particularly problematic homeless schizophrenic man who was the beneficiary of a multi-million dollar trust, who routinely threatened to sue the bank as they tried to make contact with him. He was sure they were trying to kill him. He disrupted retail bank operations  there almost as much as a bank robber with his antics, doing things like throwing water balloons in the front lobby to show his distaste for the institution.

Trust departments work differently from other parts of bank operations in this respect. The OP's experience with ordinary retail banking sheds no light on this practice. Sometimes they are asked prior to the testator's death if they will act, but this only happens a minority of the time. Usually, they are approached by the lawyer handling the affairs of the decedent for the decedent's next of kin who presents the will and/or trust instrument to them.

I know this from first hand experience, including some foreign trusts. For the first couple of years of my practice, I had lunch once a month with bank trust officers from almost all of the banks in the city where I worked. I've dealt with them regularly for decades after that.

Incidentally, this is one respect in which the business practice in common law countries doesn't differ materially from one country to another.

Answer (score 1):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

I'm choosing to interpret your question as "can a corporation be compelled to act as a trustee?" since, if there is nothing which can compel them, then the question of "why would they act?" is a matter for their internal decision-making policy rather than a legal question. The latter question is opinion-based and off-topic.

From Lewin on Trusts 20th Ed.:

> 13-007 - No one can be compelled to accept a trust.[1] Thus the
> intended trustee can disclaim the office as a whole at any time before
> acceptance, but not afterwards.[...]
>
> How a trust is disclaimed
>
> Deed preferred
>
> 13-008 - Preferably, the disclaimer should be by deed, as a deed is
> clear evidence and admits of no ambiguity. It should be a deed poll
> and be expressed as a disclaimer. [...]
>
> Other modes
>
> 13-009 - A trust may also be disclaimed by writing under hand, by a
> defence, at the bar of the court or by an oral refusal to act.
>
> Implied disclaimer
>
> 13-010 - In addition, a disclaimer may be implied from conduct
> inconsistent with acceptance [...]
>
> Time for disclaimer
>
> 13-012 - While it is prudent for a trustee who wishes to disclaim to
> execute a deed of disclaimer without delay, there is no rule that a
> disclaimer must be made at any particular time before acceptance, and
> disclaimers have been successful after long periods of delay.

[1] Robinson v Pett (1734) 3 Peere Wms. 249.

So, the answer to the question is, a corporation who was unaware of the trust will only act as a trustee if they choose to for their own reasons (e.g. they agree to enter into a contract with a beneficiary to do so).